# With java jdk 1.7 64-bit, a for loop using an int is 20+ times faster than a for loop with a long. Why?

Tags: java, 64-bit

See edits below

There is no casting going on with the termination check.  I would think the < and the ++ would be as fast with ints and longs on a 64bit machine.  But I guess not?

**int:  65 milliseconds:**

```
public void testWTF() throws Exception {
    int runs = 10;
    long hs = 0;
    long timeSum = 0;
    for (int run = 0; run < runs; run++) {
        int term = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // ***** loop to be tested ******
        for (int i = 0; i < term; i++) {
            hs++;
        }
        timeSum += (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        System.out.println("hs = " + hs);
        hs = 0;

    }
    System.out.println("timeSum = " + timeSum);
    System.out.println("avg time = " + (timeSum / runs) + " for " + runs + " runs");
    System.out.println("hs = " + hs);
}
```

**long:  1445 milliseconds**

```
public void testWTF() throws Exception {
    int runs = 10;
    long hs = 0;
    long timeSum = 0;
    for (int run = 0; run < runs; run++) {
        long term = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // ***** loop to be tested ******
        for (long i = 0; i < term; i++) {
            hs++;
        }
        timeSum += (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        System.out.println("hs = " + hs);
        hs = 0;

    }
    System.out.println("timeSum = " + timeSum);
    System.out.println("avg time = " + (timeSum / runs) + " for " + runs + " runs");
    System.out.println("hs = " + hs);
}
```

hardware:  64-bit Xeon running windows 7 64bit.

**edit:  I updated this to do several iterations.  For 1 million runs with the int version, the average time is 65 milliseconds.   The long version takes too long for 1 million, 1000 and even 100.  For 10 runs the average time is 1447 milliseconds.**

Also, I'm using hs outside the loop so that the loop does not get jitted away.

Comment: Did you run this multiple times? If you just ran it once that could explain the huge time difference.

Comment: I can not confirm your result. With the int version i the avg time is 1475ms and with the long version 1463ms for 10 runs. Running on Windows 8 64 Bit with JDK 7 update 13 64 Bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very bad/unreliable/unrealistic way of doing benchmarks, since the JIT isn't really given a chance to do much optimization -- you only run the benchmarks once, and you measure the first run.

Basically, Java's JIT will optimize your code significantly more once it sees your code getting used extensively.  In a real program, the JIT will be optimizing any critical loops, so if you want a benchmark that mimics the real world, you have to convince the JIT to kick in.

The simplest way to get an accurate benchmark in Java is to use a tool like [Caliper](http://caliper.googlecode.com) that knows how to properly warm up the JIT and get accurate measurements, and then see if the results are more consistent.

Comment: It looks like the JIT is smart enough to eliminate the loop completely for `int`, probably just replacing the whole loop with the assignment `hs = term`.  The bytecode is more complicated for `long`, probably indicating the JIT isn't smart enough to do it in that case.  Either way, it's not exactly a realistic benchmark.

Comment: I modified it a bit so that hs has to be used outside the loop.  That gives about 65ms for the int.

Comment: It can sometimes take `10000` runs of a benchmark for the JIT to kick in.  Bring `term` down to something more reasonable and try the comparison with running both benchmarks a huge number of times.